# Prove that set is uncountable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$$\{f \mid f : \mathbb{N} → \{0, 1\}\} - \{f\mid f : \{0, 1\} → \mathbb{N}\}$$
Where $f$ is a function. Prove that this difference is an uncountable set.

I am pretty stuck on how to start this problem. I understand that the set from $0$ to $1$ is uncountable while the set of natural numbers is countable, but I can't seem to start off the proof.

Comment: Calling the sets $A$ and $B$, it seems that $B \cap A = \varnothing$. None of the elements of $A$ have domain $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: You can repeat the logic from Cantor's diagonal proof: suppose there was some bijection between the natural numbers and these functions. Can you construct a new function which cannot have a natural number mapped to it?

Comment: @William why is it the case that none of the elements of A have that domain? If its the case, then this is definitely uncountable, since set B is uncountable, due to the fact that it is mapping elements from an uncountable domain which means there are an infinite amount of elements in its set?

Comment: I agree with @William. Since the sets are disjoint, the difference is $\{f \mid f : \Bbb{N} \to \{0, 1\}\}$, which is uncountable straightforwardly by Cantor (well, it has the usual bijection with the power set of $\Bbb{N}$). In general, if $A$ is uncountable and $B$ is countable, then $A - B$ is uncountable. Why? As always, we have $A \subseteq (A - B) \cup B$. If $A - B$ and $B$ are countable, then so is $(A - B) \cup B$, and hence $A$. This would be a contradiction.

Comment: "I understand that the set from 0 to 1 is uncountable": that does not make sense

Comment: @miracle173 I would guess they mean $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Note that what you have is $\{0,1\}$, not $[0,1]$. The latter is the interval that contains all real numbers $x$ with $0\leq x\leq1$ (I think that's what you are calling "the set from $0$ to $1$"). But that interval is *not part of this problem*. The set `{0,1}` is the set that has exactly *two* elements, namely $0$ and $1$, and nothing else.

Comment: I still fail to see why none of the elements of A have domain {0.1}

Comment: If $f:\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}$, then the domain of $f$ must be all of $\mathbb N$, which is not the same as $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: All elements of $A$ have domain $\mathbb N$ which is not $\{0,1\}$

Comment: But the set of natural numbers include 0 and 1, how are the sets disjoint?

Comment: As pointed out it makes little sense to take the difference between two disjoint sets (you'll end up with the first). The first set is uncountable, while the second set is countable (easy to check). Is the goal of the problem perhaps that if you would take away a countable part from the first uncountable set A it is still uncountable? You could do this by making a bijection between a subset of the first set A and the second set B you are considering. Then take away the subset  from A and show that the result is still an uncountable set.

Comment: @Michel But how are they disjoint?

Comment: @user737163: $\mathbb N$ and $\{0,1\}$ are not disjoint, because $\mathbb N \cap \{0,1\}=\{0,1\}$. But they are different, which means $\mathbb N\neq  \{0,1\}$. This is   because $\mathbb N \not \subseteq  \{0,1\}$.

Comment: If we have two functions $f:\Bbb N\to X$ and $g:\{0,1\}\to X$, then $f\neq g$. Sure, $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ *may* be the same as $g(0)$ and $g(1)$, but they still are different functions overall.

Comment: But technically couldn't $0$ mapping to $0$ be a common pair, thus the functions aren't disjoint? I'm not saying they're the same functions, just that there are some elements in their complement?

Comment: These sets as disjoint as sets of functions. The domains of the functions in set A and set B intersect. But the functions are distinct. No element of the first set is an element of the second set and vice versa.

Comment: "But technically couldn't 0 mapping to 0 be a common pair, thus the functions aren't disjoint? I'm not saying they're the same functions, just that there are some elements in their complement?" You can subtract the functions as relations (= sets of pairs). This is not the same  taking the difference between the sets of functions you display (which is taking away functions from the first set that belong to the second). You are operating in different contexts in that case and need to reformulate your original problem (if this is your intention).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments point out that the two sets we have are, in fact, disjoint, so we have that the cardinality of their difference is just the cardinality of the first set. Even without using this fact, we can still show that we have an uncountable set.

The set $\{f\mid f:\Bbb N\to\{0,1\}\}$ has cardinality $2^{|\mathbb N|}=2^{\aleph_0}$. To see this, notice that each element of $\Bbb N$ can be mapped to one of two elements, either $0$ or $1$.

The set $\{f\mid f:\{0,1\}\to\Bbb N\}$ has cardinality $|\Bbb N|^2=\aleph_0$. To see this, notice that each element of $\{0,1\}$ can be mapped to one of $|\Bbb N|$ elements, either $0,1,2,3,\dots$.

We start with $2^{\aleph_0}$ (uncountably many) elements and remove *at most* $\aleph_0$ (countably many) elements, so our set difference has at least $2^{\aleph_0}-\aleph_0=2^{\aleph_0}$ elements, i.e., it is uncountable.